# Server State - SQL Agent Jobs

Tags: sql-server-agent

I have a user who has SQL Server State Permissions so he can monitor his databases and processes.

However, there are others that are not the users dbs

When a sql agent job failes on the other db's he gets notified.

Can I stop this and if so, how?

Much appreciated

Thanks Taz

Comment: Do you an alert for each job?  What is the process that notifies him?

Comment: A SQL Server Agent job doesn't belong to a database. Sounds like you need to use different operators so you can segregate who gets alerted per job.